# How to add subdomain names and redirect them to local servers in nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain, reverse-proxy

After reading a few instructions and finding only half answers, here goes a small request:

I have a dynamic ip with a ddns service pointing "example.com" to my ip. Locally, my router redirects the access port to a win2016 server on which I run Nginx and I am trying to configure it so that I can access different local servers (server1:port1, server1:port2, server2:port3) using "subdomain.example.com".

So I am missing something, as all I managed to do is redirect the main example.com to anything I want OR redirect "example.com/name" to a local server.

What should I do to be able to access "server1:port1, server1:port2, server2:port3" using "subdomain1.example.com, subdomain2.example.com, subdomain3.example.com"

I am pulling my hair out.

I removed everything I tested in nginx.conf and all that remains is attached - which redirects to one of my servers.

```
events {

worker_connections  1024;

} 

http {

include       mime.types;

default_type  application/octet-stream;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
listen 80;
server_name "example.com";

location / {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:"port";
}   

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: First you should ensure that DDNS points all `*.example.com` subdomains (and the main domain, too) to your public IP. Then you should define a `server` block in the nginX config for each of these subdomains - and then put a `location /` block in each of them, proxying to the corresponding local server AND port.

Comment: hello. "First you should ensure that DDNS points all *.example.com " this i did not know. I have to check if no-ip free service does this...

Comment: Well, if your subdomains do not point to your public IP - then you can not access them outside of your local network.

Comment: I thought that subdomains will redirect automatically to the parent domain. I managed to resolve this. Thank you very much!

Comment: They won't - there is no such term as "redirection" in DNS. It is just a simple key/value map.